# Setting from values in Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In Asp.Net MVC, I have a form for creating Advertisement.

```
public class AdvertisementViewModel
{
    public AdvertisementViewModel()
    {
        this.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    // other properties
 }
```

StartTime does not come from the user, but I set it in the constructor.

In my view, user will populate all the input fields and post the model to controller's ActionMethod, where the model will be saved.

Now in order for the StartTime to be passed to ActionMethod, I am adding it as a hidden field to the view so it would be posted back.

**Is there a better way of setting start time, as I don't really need it in the view?**

I know I can set it in the post action method, but I have different advertisement types and I have to set the StartTime in multiple places. All of my Advertisement types are derived from a base class where StartTime is defined.

Comment: Its already in your constructor, so it will be set when the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes your model in the POST method

Comment: You can try this: `public DateTime StartTime { get { return DateTime.Now; } }`

Comment: Use `[Bind(Exclude="StartTime")]`. You can also apply `[IgnoreDataMember]` and `[JsonIgnore]` if you don't need this property in the view at all.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Thanks, the constructor creates the model in Get method. Then I display the View, which will post back the model. Are you saying that if I remove the Hidden field, the default model binder will still pass the value to post method?

Comment: Yes - The `DefaultModelBinder` first initializes your model (using `Activator.CreateInstance()`) - the constructor is called and the value of `StartTime` will be set (to `DateTime.Now`), then it sets the property values from the request. You do not need any input for it

Comment: @Ricardo: Thanks, but if I do this then in other places where I need to read the StartTime to see if the Ad is expired or not, I will always get the current time...?

Comment: Having said that, a malicious user could post a value for it in which case the default value would be overwritten - which is one reason (of many reasons) why you should always use a view model, and the view model will not have a `StartDate` property.

Comment: @Stephen: So I should just set the value to Now, in each Post Action Method?

Comment: Typically you would set it in the POST method when you map the view model to the data model. But I am not understanding what you mean by _but I have different advertisement types and I have to set the StartTime in multiple places_

Comment: Say I have ClothesAd, HouseAd and MotorsAd. I have corresponding ViewModels and ActionMethods. So I can Set the StartDate in PostHouse, PostMotors, etc... Or should I remove StartTime from my ViewModels all together and set in data model constructor?

Comment: @HFB, Personally, I would set it in the data models constructor